# How to Transform N number of React SPAs into Multi page App?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-redux, webpack-4

[image]
How to Isolate two Entry Points (Style sheets & Scripts) into React App?
How the Web Pack Configuration should Look Like?
Need to have two completely different sets of CSS & JS files for

1. Public User
2. Private User (Authenticated ones)

Often Public and private style sheets & JavaScript imports are conflicting to each other.

> How to configure React so that both could co-exist?

1. I wish if it was allowed to have two Index.Htmls we could configure,
   easily.
2. How does community address such needs in SPA?

Comment: There is something called JS lazy-loading you don't load some JS unless you need it, same goes for CSS. If user is authenticated load this new resources and remove this previous for unauthenticated users. But I can't really see the actual problem components are separate views and you simply load correct view if user is authenticated. Other html? - You can use redirect.

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to prevent unauthorized users to even see the 'private' js files?
Cause if not, you can gate the data in the server and even if your private views are rendered, they will have no content.

Comment: For me this sounds more like a backend topic. What you could do is develop normally the your application in react, pointing to some "index.js". Your backend can make sure for example that for an unauthorized user it gets redirect to another url (or provide just a different index.js). If you want to really do it in the FE than you would need to use React-Router, check if user is Authenticated (Cookies / Backend Call) and based on that the BE returns a set of scripts to load. You than load missing stuff.

Comment: I find this question to be way to vague and hard to understand. Can you come up with a few example files showing what the actual problems are that you're trying to overcome? This doesn't actually seem that difficult and I've dealt with far more complex architecture. But it's very hard to tell what's blocking you without specific examples.

Comment: This question is too broad. Due to the bounty, it wont be closed, also got lot of upvotes.